# What's the error in my foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Following is my multidimensional array named `$prev_map_data`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 2
            [class_name] => II
            [class_checked] => 1
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 81
                            [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                            [subject_checked] => 1
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 81
                        )

                )

        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [class_id] => 3
        [class_name] => III
        [class_checked] => 1
        [class_subjects] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [cs_map_id] => 155
                        [subject_name] => Hidi
                        [subject_checked] => 1
                        [teacher_cs_id] => 155
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [cs_map_id] => 156
                        [subject_name] => 11 Maths
                        [subject_checked] => 1
                        [teacher_cs_id] => 156
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [cs_map_id] => 157
                        [subject_name] => 11 Science
                        [subject_checked] => 1
                        [teacher_cs_id] => 157
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

I want to get all the values from key `[class_id]` one by one and push the values in an array `$data`. But getting the warning

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I'm not understanding what is wrong with my code. Can any one help me to improve my code and append the values to the new array? Thanks in advance. My code is as follows :

```
 $prev_map_data  = $objTeacherClassesSubjects->GetClassSubjectMappingsbyTeacherId ($request, $teacher_class_subjects_error_messages);
   foreach($prev_map_data as $map_id) {
              $cls_data[] = $map_id['class_id'];
          }
    }
```

Comment: `$prev_map_data` seems to be not an array. `var_dump` it.

Comment: Have you checked that you got non-empty array `$prev_map_data`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$teacher_class_subjects_error_messages);
   foreach($prev_map_data as $iKey => $iVal) {
              $cls_data[] = $iVal['class_id'];
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$prev_map_data` is not an array. use `var_export($prev_map_data);` to see if it is an array

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($prev_map_data) && is_array($prev_map_data)) {
  foreach($prev_map_data as $key=>$map_id) {
     if(is_array($map_id))
       $cls_data[] = $map_id['class_id'];
     else
       echo '$map_id is not an array!';
  }
} else {
  echo '$prev_map_data is not an array or it is empty!';
}
```